# connecting common anode rgb led

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, led, breadboard

Mistakenly purchased common anode RGB LEDs and haven't been able to find any examples showing how to connect to Raspberry Pi 3. All diagrams describe the common cathode type.

I understand the logic is reversed... So 0 is brightest. But I'm not sure how to connect the anode pin vs the RGB pins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connect the common anode pin to 3.3 volt and each of the other pins to a GPIO (add a current limiting resistor between the LED and the GPIO pin. To Light one of the colors set the corresponding GPIO pin low.